# Stop matplotlib repeating labels in legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

Here is a very simplified example:

```
xvalues = [2,3,4,6]

for x in xvalues:
    plt.axvline(x,color='b',label='xvalues')

plt.legend()
```

[image]

The legend will now show 'xvalues' as a blue line 4 times in the legend.
Is there a more elegant way of fixing this than the following?

```
for i,x in enumerate(xvalues):
    if not i:
        plt.axvline(x,color='b',label='xvalues')
    else:
        plt.axvline(x,color='b')
```

[image]

Comment: I like the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385639/duplicate-items-in-legend-in-matplotlib

Answer (score 202, accepted):

`plt.legend` takes as parameters

1. A list of axis handles which are `Artist` objects
2. A list of labels which are strings

These parameters are both optional defaulting to `plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()`.
You can remove duplicate labels by putting them in a dictionary before calling `legend`. This is because dicts can't have duplicate keys.

For example:

### For Python versions < 3.7

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
by_label = OrderedDict(zip(labels, handles))
plt.legend(by_label.values(), by_label.keys())
```

### For Python versions > 3.7

As of Python 3.7, dictionaries retain input order by default. Thus, there is no need for `OrderedDict` form the collections module.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
by_label = dict(zip(labels, handles))
plt.legend(by_label.values(), by_label.keys())
```

[image]

[Docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html) for `plt.legend`

Answer (score 13):

```
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
handle_list, label_list = [], []
for handle, label in zip(handles, labels):
    if label not in label_list:
        handle_list.append(handle)
        label_list.append(label)
plt.legend(handle_list, label_list)
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation with your answer.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know if this can be considered "elegant", but you can have your label a variable that gets set to `"_nolegend_"` after first usage:

```
my_label = "xvalues"
xvalues = [2,3,4,6]

for x in xvalues:
    plt.axvline(x, color='b', label=my_label)
    my_label = "_nolegend_"

plt.legend()
```

This can be generalized using a dictionary of labels if you have to put several labels:

```
my_labels = {"x1" : "x1values", "x2" : "x2values"}
x1values = [1, 3, 5]
x2values = [2, 4, 6]

for x in x1values:
    plt.axvline(x, color='b', label=my_labels["x1"])
    my_labels["x1"] = "_nolegend_"
for x in x2values:
    plt.axvline(x, color='r', label=my_labels["x2"])
    my_labels["x2"] = "_nolegend_"

plt.legend()
```

[image: Figure with 2 different labels]

(Answer inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/19386045/1878788)

Answer (score 6):

## Problem - 3D Array

Questions: [Nov 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13588920/10450752), [Oct 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19385639/10450752)

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.random.random((2, 100, 4))
b = np.random.random((2, 100, 4))
c = np.random.random((2, 100, 4))
```

## Solution - dict uniqueness

For my case `_nolegend_` ([bli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41228380/10450752) and [DSM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19386045/10450752)) would not work, nor would `label if i==0`.  [ecatmur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13589144/10450752)'s answer uses `get_legend_handles_labels` and reduces the legend down with `collections.OrderedDict`.  [Fons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56253636/10450752) demonstrates this is possible without an import.

Inline with these answers, I suggest using `dict` for unique labels.

```py
# Step-by-step
ax = plt.gca()                      # Get the axes you need
a = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()  # a = [(h1 ... h2) (l1 ... l2)]  non unique
b = {l:h for h,l in zip(*a)}        # b = {l1:h1, l2:h2}             unique
c = [*zip(*b.items())]              # c = [(l1 l2) (h1 h2)]
d = c[::-1]                         # d = [(h1 h2) (l1 l2)]
plt.legend(*d)
```

Or

```py
plt.legend(*[*zip(*{l:h for h,l in zip(*ax.get_legend_handles_labels())}.items())][::-1])
```

Maybe less legible and memorable than [Matthew Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588920/stop-matplotlib-repeating-labels-in-legend/26550501#26550501)'s solution.  *Code golf welcome.*

## Example

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.random.random((2, 100, 4))
b = np.random.random((2, 100, 4))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot(*a, 'C0', label='a')
ax.plot(*b, 'C1', label='b')

ax.legend(*[*zip(*{l:h for h,l in zip(*ax.get_legend_handles_labels())}.items())][::-1])
# ax.legend()   # Old,  ^ New

plt.show()
```

Comment: Elegant Solution! This can also be used to combine labels from multiple axes.

Answer (score 3):

Based on answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13589144/9132798 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/19386045/9132798 
`plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()[1]` gives a list of names, it is possible to check if the label is already in the list while in the loop plotting (`label= name[i] if name[i] not in plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()[1] else ''`). 
For the given example this solution would look like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xvalues = [2,3,4,6]

for x in xvalues:
    plt.axvline(x,color='b',\
    label= 'xvalues' if 'xvalues' \
            not in plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()[1] else '')

plt.legend()
```

Which is much shorter than https://stackoverflow.com/a/13589144/9132798 and more flexible than https://stackoverflow.com/a/19386045/9132798 as it could be use for any kind of loop any plot function in the loop individually.
However, for many cycles it probably slower than https://stackoverflow.com/a/13589144/9132798.

Answer (score 1):

These code snippets didn't work for me personally. I was plotting two different groups in two different colors.  The legend would show two red markers and two blue markers, when I only wanted to see one per color.  I'll paste a simplified version of what did work for me:

#### Import statements

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerLine2D
```

#### Plot data

```
points_grp, = plt.plot(x[grp_idx], y[grp_idx], color=c.c[1], marker=m, ms=4, lw=0, label=leglab[1])        
points_ctrl, = plt.plot(x[ctrl_idx], y[ctrl_idx], color=c.c[0], marker=m, ms=4, lw=0, label=leglab[0])
```

#### Add legend

```
points_dict = {points_grp: HandlerLine2D(numpoints=1),points_ctrl: HandlerLine2D(numpoints=1)}
leg = ax.legend(fontsize=12, loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.03),handler_map=points_dict)
```