# python multiple lines as one group

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

If I plot various disjoint lines with one call as follows...

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> x = [random.randint(0,9) for i in range(10)]
>>> y = [random.randint(0,9) for i in range(10)]
>>> data = []
>>> for i in range(0,10,2):
...     data.append((x[i], x[i+1]))
...     data.append((y[i], y[i+1]))
... 
>>> print(data)
[(6, 4), (4, 3), (6, 5), (0, 4), (0, 0), (2, 2), (2, 0), (6, 5), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
>>> plt.plot(*data)
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x0000022A20046E48>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x0000022A2004D048>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x0000022A2004D9B0>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x0000022A20053208>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x0000022A20053A20>]
>>> plt.show()
```

[image]

I cant figure out how to I get python/matplotlib to see it as a single plot, of the same color, linewidth, ect and the same legend entry...

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind them all being merged into one line than you should simply use `plt.plot(x,y)`. However I think you would like to keep them as separate lines. For this you can specify the style arguments to your plot comamnd and then use the code from [Stop matplotlib repeating labels in legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588920/stop-matplotlib-repeating-labels-in-legend) to prevent multiple legend entries.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from collections import OrderedDict

x = [np.random.randint(0,9) for i in range(10)]
y = [np.random.randint(0,9) for i in range(10)]
data = []
for i in range(0,10,2):
     data.append((x[i], x[i+1]))
     data.append((y[i], y[i+1]))

#Plot all with same style and label.
plt.plot(*data,linestyle='-',color='blue',label='LABEL')

#Single Legend Label
handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
by_label = OrderedDict(zip(labels, handles))
plt.legend(by_label.values(), by_label.keys())

#Show Plot
plt.show()
```

Giving you
[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
import numpy as np
d = np.asarray(data)
plt.plot(d[:,0],d[:,1])
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't think this works because it connects endpoints of different lines